# Why characters shows up like � after dealing with them?

Tags: c++, char, utf

I'm making kind of encryption algorithm but I have a terrible problem when dealing with some special chars like "à","é".

Whenever I make a copy in memory or something like that this problem comes out. I made this little code to explain it :

```
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char ar[]="à";
    char bf[]="a";
    char cd;

    cout <<"Before:\n" << ar <<"\t" <<bf << endl;

    cd=ar[0];
    ar[0]=bf[0];
    bf[0]=cd;

    cout <<"After:\n" << ar  <<"\t" <<bf << endl;

}
```

And as I know just few about this I couldn't solve it. How could I fix this?

Comment: sorry ..
output =>
Before:
à a
After:
a�

so u see �

Comment: using `wchar_t` instead of `char` might help

Comment: im dealing with arrays in ma code ...and using wchar_t to store the char in cd didn't help :p

Comment: Did you run your encryption algorithm on the question before posting it? *ssmthng lik dat* is not English!

Comment: @Praetorian that runs atleast in mine

Comment: @Praetorian Not just the question, I think the code too.

Comment: add this: `cout << "ar is " << sizeof(ar) << " characters, bf is " << sizeof(bf) << " characters" << endl;` and you'll find that 'ar' is actually a utf8 or multi-byte character sequence, not just a single character.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know we cannot find character `à` in ascii codes. So, use wchar_t instead of char. Because char only 8 bits and can only deal with 256 different characters.

```
im dealing with arrays in ma code ...and using wchar_t to store the char in cd didn't help
```

In that case use [wchar_t](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wchar_t/&ei=IhuqUbzKI8SErgf3v4DIBA&usg=AFQjCNHKbCWU7_SIQcEJTGhLPGqrTmsNdw&bvm=bv.47244034,d.bmk) array.

Declaring `wchar_t` string

`wchar_t wptr[] = L"Your String";`

Declaring `wchar_t` char

```
`wchar_t wc=L'A';
```

To declare a wchar_t char array

```
 `wchar_t aa[]={L'A',L'B'};`
```

So your code becomes

```
   #include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

wchar_t ar[]=L"à";
wchar_t bf[]=L"a";
wchar_t cd;

cout <<"Before:\n" <<ar <<"\t" <<bf <<endl;

cd=ar[0];
ar[0]=bf[0];
bf[0]=cd;

cout <<"After:\n" <<ar  <<"\t" <<bf <<endl;

}
```

That solves the problem

Comment: compiler says :
int-array initialized from non-wide string

Comment: @user2355950 you need to add `L` in front. e.g - `= L"a";`

Comment: Its done but when printing arrays it gives me memory addresses instead of arrays content (and considering it a pointer i added '*' then it gives me ASCII decimal values) 
==>
 Before:
0xbfc4aaf4 0xbfc4aaec
After:
0xbfc4aaf4 0xbfc4aaec
then when i added * it shows like this
Before:
224 97
so what's the matter o.O ? i want to print the char not its decimal value

Comment: @user2355950: You may need `std::wcout` for Wide characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this program from a DOS command prompt on a Windows operating system, you must set the command window to use an ANSI compatible active code page. The following code page works on my system:

```
chcp 1252
```

Enter the chcp command before running your program.